# I can get error in this code

Tags: java, selenium

```
 public class GmailGoogle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\ChromeDriver");

        WebDriver wd= new ChromeDriver();
        wd.manage().window().maximize();
        wd.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier");

        WebElement signin = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="Email"]"));
        signin.sendKeys("sakthe");

        WebElement next = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="next"]"));
        next.click();

    }
}
```

Left hand side of an operator must be variable while Running in selenium webDriver..Any one can help me to fix this Error

Comment: can you tell me the line no where your are getting this error

Comment: Please post well formatted code only.

Comment: It would also really help if you would indent your code when you post. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints. Are you sure the problem is in this code rather than in Javascript you're exercising?

Comment: you certainly have some issue in these two statements: `By.xpath("//*[@id="Email"]")` and `"//*[@id="next"]")`. Please check it.

Comment: These 2 statements are xpath which is taken from that page I want to test..I take xpath from Right click inspect element , copy Xpath....Is this correct procedure to Take Xpath..?@JonSkeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the double quotes in the xpath to single quotes.

`//*[@id="Email"]` to `//*[@id='Email']`

`//*[@id="next"]` to `//*[@id='next']`

`E:\\ChromeDriver` to `E:/ChromeDriver.exe`

Your scrips works fine after this.

Comment: just now I changed...But I had Received this Error in this time - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property@Striker

Comment: I assume that you are new to selenium. Give the full path to chrimedriver and it will work

Comment: yes I am new to selenium..again it'll show the same error here is the code-package practice;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class GmailGoogle {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  System.setProperty("WebDriver.chrome.driver","E:/ChromeDriver.exe");
  WebDriver wd= new ChromeDriver();

Comment: WebDriver to small letters and ChromeDriver to ChromeDriver.exe

Comment: sorry to disturbing you... I changed the code....but again I am having the same error.....

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system prop? Error?

Comment: Have you downloaded the chromedriver. Exe and have placed in E drive in the path?

Comment: Thanks.....It works...what I did the mistake is..I placed the chromedriver in folder....Now I placed In E: location.....